# Why Is LoadBalancer Service Still Pending?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I created my kubernetes cluster using KubeSpray on AWS. Now I am trying to get the Ingress Controller to work. My understanding is that I need to apply  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.34.1/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml which will create all the resources that I need including a network load balancer.

However, the LoadBalancer never comes out of pending status:

```
$ kubectl -n ingress-nginx get svc
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.233.28.147   <pending>     80:31304/TCP,443:31989/TCP   11m
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.233.58.231   <none>        443/TCP                      11m
```

Describing the service does not seem to provide any interesting information.

```
$ kubectl -n ingress-nginx describe service ingress-nginx-controller
Name:                     ingress-nginx-controller
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                          app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=0.34.1
                          helm.sh/chart=ingress-nginx-2.11.1
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{"service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol":"tcp","serv...
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: 60
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: true
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.233.28.147
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31304/TCP
Endpoints:                10.233.97.22:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31989/TCP
Endpoints:                10.233.97.22:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Local
HealthCheck NodePort:     30660
Events:                   <none>
```

How can this issue be debugged?

UPDATE:

The output of `kubectl -n kube-system logs -l component=kube-controller-manager` is:

```
E0801 21:12:29.429759       1 job_controller.go:793] pods "ingress-nginx-admission-create-" is forbidden: error looking up service account ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-admission: serviceaccount "ingress-nginx-admission" not found
E0801 21:12:29.429788       1 job_controller.go:398] Error syncing job: pods "ingress-nginx-admission-create-" is forbidden: error looking up service account ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-admission: serviceaccount "ingress-nginx-admission" not found
I0801 21:12:29.429851       1 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Job", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-admission-create", UID:"4faad8c5-9b1e-4c23-a942-94be181d590f", APIVersion:"batch/v1", ResourceVersion:"1506255", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedCreate' Error creating: pods "ingress-nginx-admission-create-" is forbidden: error looking up service account ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-admission: serviceaccount "ingress-nginx-admission" not found
E0801 21:12:29.483485       1 job_controller.go:793] pods "ingress-nginx-admission-patch-" is forbidden: error looking up service account ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-admission: serviceaccount "ingress-nginx-admission" not found
E0801 21:12:29.483512       1 job_controller.go:398] Error syncing job: pods "ingress-nginx-admission-patch-" is forbidden: error looking up service account ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-admission: serviceaccount "ingress-nginx-admission" not found
I0801 21:12:29.483679       1 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Job", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-admission-patch", UID:"92ee0e43-2711-4b37-9fd6-958ef3c95b31", APIVersion:"batch/v1", ResourceVersion:"1506257", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedCreate' Error creating: pods "ingress-nginx-admission-patch-" is forbidden: error looking up service account ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-admission: serviceaccount "ingress-nginx-admission" not found
I0801 21:12:39.436590       1 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Job", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-admission-create", UID:"4faad8c5-9b1e-4c23-a942-94be181d590f", APIVersion:"batch/v1", ResourceVersion:"1506255", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'SuccessfulCreate' Created pod: ingress-nginx-admission-create-85x58
I0801 21:12:39.489303       1 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Job", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-admission-patch", UID:"92ee0e43-2711-4b37-9fd6-958ef3c95b31", APIVersion:"batch/v1", ResourceVersion:"1506257", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'SuccessfulCreate' Created pod: ingress-nginx-admission-patch-sn8xv
I0801 21:12:41.448425       1 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Job", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-admission-create", UID:"4faad8c5-9b1e-4c23-a942-94be181d590f", APIVersion:"batch/v1", ResourceVersion:"1506297", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Completed' Job completed
I0801 21:12:42.481264       1 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Job", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-admission-patch", UID:"92ee0e43-2711-4b37-9fd6-958ef3c95b31", APIVersion:"batch/v1", ResourceVersion:"1506304", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Completed' Job completed
```

I do have the PodSecurityPolicy admission controller enabled. I updated the `deploy.yaml` file with the following changes.

- Add the following to all ClusterRole and Role resources.

```
- apiGroups:      [policy]
  resources:      [podsecuritypolicies]
  resourceNames:  [privileged]
  verbs:          [use]
```

- Add the following to the end of the file.

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.11.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.34.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx
    namespace: default
```

**Question Responses:**

- The IAM roles were created by the ansible playbooks in the Kubespray `contrib/terraform/aws` directory.
- A classic load balancer was created for the apiserver by those ansible scripts.

Comment: The [kube-controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/) is the daemon that creates AWS resources on your behalf; can you check the logs to see if there are any errors? (e.g., `kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system -l component=kube-controller-manager`. Have you created the [IAM roles](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/tree/master/contrib/aws_iam/) needed for your master and node instances? Can you check if an NLB was created?

Comment: The install is almost certainly missing `--cloud-controller=aws --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud_config` on the apiserver and controller-manager pods, but without knowing the specific version of kubespray it's hard to say for sure

Comment: I am using the master branch of kubespray. My installation does not have any mention of the cloud-controller. I am researching the topic.

Comment: "To deploy kubespray on AWS uncomment the cloud_provider option in group_vars/all.yml and set it to 'aws'." [Read here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/aws.md) for more information on aws specific configuration of kubespray. @DavidMedinets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two answers to this question.

**one** - add the `cloud-provider` option to your `ansible-playbook` command as shown below.

```
ansible-playbook \
  -vvvvv \
  -i ./inventory/hosts \
  ./cluster.yml \
  -e ansible_user=centos \
  -e cloud_provider=aws \
  -e bootstrap_os=centos \
  --become \
  --become-user=root \
  --flush-cache \
  -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=$PKI_PRIVATE_PEM \
  | tee kubespray-cluster-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M").log
```

**two**

Uncomment the cloud_provider option in group_vars/all.yml and set it to 'aws'

**proof**

I've tried the first answer.

```
$ kubectl -n ingress-nginx get svc
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                                     PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.233.57.196   aa....amazonaws.com   80:32111/TCP,443:31854/TCP   109s
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.233.11.133   <none>                                                                          443/TCP                      109s
```